# RecyclerView strange adapter and rows behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView have two problems :

- The first problem is when i am finished working with its activity and press back button it creates the same activity again but after removing some row (Mostly from the end) ,, I don't know if the problem is it  creates the view on multiple phases or what .
- The second problem is when i press some button(Like button for example) it recreates the activity with the new result at each time it is pressed .

here is my Adapter

```
    package com.example.agh.grad.Adapters;



import android.Manifest; import android.app.Activity; import 
android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import android.content.pm.PackageManager; import android.net.Uri; import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; import android.support.v7.widget.CardView; import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.TextView; import com.example.agh.grad.ItemClickListner; import com.example.agh.grad.Models.Services; import com.example.agh.grad.R; import com.example.agh.grad.SearchServices; import com.example.agh.grad.ServiceDetail; import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; import org.parceler.Parcels; import java.util.ArrayList; import butterknife.BindView; import butterknife.ButterKnife; /** * Created by cz on 17/06/17. */ public class recylerServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recylerServiceAdapter.ViewHolder> { ArrayList<Services> service; Context context; ItemClickListner clickListner; public recylerServiceAdapter(ArrayList<Services> service, Context context) { this.service = service; this.context = context; } @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recyler_services, parent, false); ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v); context= parent.getContext(); return viewHolder; }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvServiceName.setText(service.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvServiceDisrption.setText(service.get(position).getServiceShortDesrption());
    holder.tvServiceProvider.setText(service.get(position).getServiceProvider());
    holder.tvLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(service.get(position).getLikes()));
    holder.tvDislikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(service.get(position).getDislikes()));
    holder.tvLocationDescrption.setText(service.get(position).getLocationAddress());


    holder.tvServiceName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    /*   Intent myIntent=   new Intent(context,SearchServices.class);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);*/
}
 });


       holder.btnLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final FirebaseDatabase firedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = firedatabase.getReference("Services");
            DatabaseReference wantedService =    ref.child(String.valueOf(service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getName()));
     final  Long uplikes=    service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLikes()+1;

            wantedService.child("likes").setValue(uplikes, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    holder.tvLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(uplikes));
                }
            });
         // TODO: 11/10/17  update on the database

            //// TODO: 05/12/17  Check state of buttons and act upon it

            holder.btnLike.setClickable(false);//// TODO: 05/12/17 set a clicked icon
            holder.btnDislike.setClickable(false);
        }
    });
    holder.btnDislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final FirebaseDatabase firedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = firedatabase.getReference("Services");
            DatabaseReference wantedService =    ref.child(String.valueOf(service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getName()));
            final  Long dislikes=    service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLikes()-1;

            wantedService.child("likes").setValue(dislikes, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    holder.tvLikeCounter.setText(String.valueOf(dislikes));
                }
            });
        }
    });
    holder.btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoneNumber()));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Ask for permission
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            context.startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent=   new Intent(context,ServiceDetail.class);

            myIntent.putExtra(SearchServices.PARCELER_TAG, Parcels.wrap(service.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) ));
            context.startActivity(myIntent);

            ((Activity)context).finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return service.size();
}

public void setClickListener(ItemClickListner itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListner = itemClickListener;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    @BindView (R.id.serviceName) TextView tvServiceName;
    @BindView (R.id.serviceProvider)TextView tvServiceProvider;
    @BindView (R.id.serviceShortDescrption)TextView tvServiceDisrption;
    @BindView (R.id.tvLikeCounter)TextView tvLikeCounter;
    @BindView (R.id.tvDislikeCounter)TextView tvDislikeCounter ;
    @BindView (R.id.locationDescrption)TextView tvLocationDescrption;

    @BindView (R.id.btnLike) Button btnLike;
    @BindView (R.id.btnDislike)  Button btnDislike;
    @BindView (R.id.btnCall) Button btnCall;
    @BindView (R.id.serviceCard) CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setTag(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }


}
}
```

and here is my activity

```
            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

List<String> arrayServices = new ArrayList<>();

RecyclerView recyclerViewServices;
recylerServiceAdapter recylerServiceAdapter;
 ArrayList<Services> newServices;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
  //  arrayServices= intent.getStringArrayListExtra("newServices");
 //   System.out.println(arrayServices.size());
   newServices = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra(SearchServices.PARCELER_TAG)) ;

Log.e( "onCreate: ",newServices.toString() );
    recyclerViewServices = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerViewServiceDetail);
    recyclerViewServices.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recylerServiceAdapter = new recylerServiceAdapter(newServices, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewServices.setAdapter(recylerServiceAdapter);



   }
      }
```

[image]

and my activity_main.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.agh.grad.MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylerViewServiceDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing activity launch mode to android:launchMode="singleTask" solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this

```
 holder.tvServiceName.setText(service.get(position).getName());
```

use

```
     holder.tvServiceName.setText(service.get(getAdapterPosition())
    .getName());
```

Comment: it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this in onClick

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```

use

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,final int position)

position
```

Comment: it changes nothing